# How to iterate mixed type Array in scala

Tags: scala

**for example**
i have given a mixed type array as follows , i'm trying to print the each and every element in the array, im able to print Array of Arrays but this one is very tricky .

`val r = Array(1,2,3,4,Array(2,3,45,6,Array(4,4,6,7)))`

i need to print this nested one.

Comment: Why would someone make such a data structure?

Comment: experimentation

Comment: it works, i didnt think abt a recursive way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
def printMixedArray(a: Array[_]) : Unit = a.foreach{ 
   case a: Array[_] => printMixedArray(a)
   case b => println(b) 
}
```